# Will "Google XML Sitemaps" plugin work without "wp_head();"

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

Will "Google XML Sitemaps" plugin work without "wp_head();"  ?

Thanx

Comment: More important question: *why is there no call to `wp_head()`*?

Answer (score 1):

This one?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/

Looks like it should as I do not see wp_head being hooked into anywhere.

Comment: yeap that one
I will give it a try without "wp_head();" ....
;)

Comment: Which makes sense, right? A sitemap usually isn't linked from the document head, but rather saved in the *document root*, where a robot would expect to find it. By the time the robot gets to the document header, it is presumably already traversing the document tree. But still my primary concern is: *why is there no call to `wp_head()`*? **No Theme** should ever omit this call. It is critical.

Comment: I have sites without "wp_head();" and they work just fine. I use as few plugins as possible. 
They load faster.
I am not an expert so maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Matus, In a "controlled environment" it's fine to omit the call to wp_head(). I've done it myself before. But after a while I stopped. I needed functionality that could only be provided by plugins utilizing the hooks used inside this function. Which lead to more than one headache. I would have to agree with Chip that no theme should ever omit it, although I do not believe that it is critical.

Comment: "wp_head();" is in my head :) when I will have problems, it will be the first thing I will think about.